# Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, godot

I'm currently developing a mobile video game using the Godot game engine. I wanted to implement Google Sign-In functionality into my game, and for this purpose, I opted to integrate Firebase. To achieve this, I created an Android plugin (module) for the engine. The class below is responsible for handling authentication:

```
class Authentication(private val activity: Activity) {

    companion object {
        private const val RC_SIGN_IN = 9001
    }

    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var googleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient

    fun signIn() {
        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(activity.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()

        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(activity, gso)

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(activity)
        auth = Firebase.auth

        val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
        activity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)

        Log.d("AfterFirebase", "Started sign in intent.")
    }

    fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        Log.d("AfterFirebase", "Authentication result code: $resultCode")
        if (data != null) {
            Log.d("AfterFirebase", "Sign In Status: ${data.extras!!.get("googleSignInStatus")}")
        }
        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)!!
                Log.d("AfterFirebase", "firebaseAuthWithGoogle: " + account.id)
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.idToken!!)
            } catch (e: ApiException) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Log.w("AfterFirebase", "Google sign in failed", e)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run the game, I encounter the following error:

> Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}

I've attempted various solutions, including adding both the SHA-1 and SHA-256 fingerprints (I compared the certificate fingerprints for both the module and the game build and confirmed they are identical) to the Firebase app configuration. Additionally, I've ensured that the latest google-services.json file has been included in the module. The Google authentication feature is enabled in the Firebase console.

Despite these efforts, the issue persists.

Comment: Are you testing on debug environment?

Comment: yes, and I have added the debug fingerprints